# Edit and/or Delete a row on CSV file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file, csv

I have a CSV file. I need to write a code that we can get a row from CSV by username. And I need to either update or delete that row from the CSV file. I was managed to get the row data by username. But I haven't got any idea how to write the code for Update or delete function. My code to get single row as follows

```
  StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"C:\Test\test.CSV"));

        UserDetailsViewModel objInput = new UserDetailsViewModel();

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
            {
                string[] values = line.Split(',');
                if (values[0] == "Bharat")
                {
                    objInput.FirstName = values[0];
                    objInput.LastName = values[1];
                    objInput.Address1 = values[2];
                    objInput.Address2 = values[3];
                    objInput.City = values[4];
                    objInput.State = values[5];
                    objInput.ZipCode = values[6];
                    break;

                }
            }
        }
        reader.Dispose();
        return View(objInput);
```

Please someone help me to write a code for Update and delete on CSV file.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? how about you write down how you would do it as a human, and then start there

Comment: So far I can able to fetch the data from CSV and stored into a array. I am still trying to update the single row on CSV without effecting whole CSV file. Right now its overwriting the whole CSV with updated values.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your desired result, using below approach.

-> First you have to read your .csv file.

-> Then iterate through every line of file, meanwhile you can choose any row for edit/delete then make change to that row and store that row into string list.

-> At last you have to write string list to file. that's all.

For Example:

```
    List<String> lines = new List<String>();
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"C:\Test\test.CSV"));)
    {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.Contains(","))
            {
                String[] split = line.Split(',');

                if (//condition for Edit record like : split[1] == "abc" etc.)
                {
                    // update that 
                    split[1] = "xyz";
                    line = String.Join(",", split);
                    lines.Add(line);
                }
                if (//condition for Delete row.)
                {
                    // don't add that row into string list
                }
            }

        }
    }

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Test\test.CSV", false))
    {
        foreach (String line in lines)
            writer.WriteLine(line);
    }
```

Comment: using the above code overwrites all whole CSV. For instance I tried to modify the data on second row. it modifies the data and overwrites the whole file and showing single updated row

Comment: Yes. it overwrite whole CSV file, but i don't think there is approach for update single row. because  if we want to modify any record in file then we have to write whole file data into file again.

Answer (score 0):

Reading and wirting csv is typically trickier than it seems to be at first glance.
Use a library like KBCsv (https://github.com/kentcb/KBCsv) for that task